# How to work out this question about similarity

Tags: r

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 <- select(iris, -c(Species)) 
iris1 <- data.frame(iris1)
Q <- dist(iris1, method = "euclidian", diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)
Q[50]
A <- as.matrix(Q)
A
Q`
```

[Dissimilarity coefficient of iris data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fT0x.png)

I have been struggling to find the right codes to be able to answer this question. I have computed the dissimilarity coefficient and worked out that there are 150 distinct dissimilarities but can't seem to figure out this question.

This is the question:

> Find the flowers with most and least similarity with flower 50 on this data. Show your codes and output for identification, along with the statement.

[This includes my code and the first part of the dissimilarity coefficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agXEj.png)

Comment: Show us your code. There are many different dissimilarity coefficients, but you do not say which one you are using. If you are using the `iris` data set in R, there are 150 observations so there are 149 dissimilarity coefficients including observation 50 (not counting the dissimilarity of observation 50 with itself).

Comment: I am needed to find out the most and least similar values with flower 50 but don't know what code to use to find this out using the iris data.frame.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting code. See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please edit the question with the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
Define a function to compute the pairwise distances between flower 50, the target flower, and the other flowers. Then apply a distance from a distances list. Finally, get the minima and maxima.

```r
similarity <- function(method = "euclidian", x, y) {
  apply(x, 1, \(row) {
    stats::dist(rbind(row, y), method = method)
  })  
}

i_target_flower <- 50
target_flower <- unlist(iris[i_target_flower, -5, drop = TRUE])

dist_list <- c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "minkowski")
sim <- lapply(dist_list, similarity, x = as.matrix(iris[-i_target_flower, -5]), y = target_flower)
names(sim) <- dist_list
sim_df <- as.data.frame(sim)

# which flowers in the original data set iris
sapply(sim_df, \(x) {
  i <- c(which.min(x), which.max(x))
  row.names(sim_df[i,])
})
#>      euclidean maximum manhattan canberra minkowski
#> [1,] "8"       "8"     "8"       "29"     "8"      
#> [2,] "119"     "119"   "119"     "119"    "119"

# corresponding distances
sapply(sim_df, \(x) x[c(which.min(x), which.max(x))])
#>      euclidean maximum manhattan   canberra minkowski
#> [1,] 0.1414214     0.1       0.2 0.03453322 0.1414214
#> [2,] 6.5145990     5.5      11.0 1.83389310 6.5145990
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>